# MySQL: Unknown system variable 'tx_read_only'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm working on a Java Swing-based application+ Hibernate+Mysql+Spring.
When I test CRUD operations, I don't have problems with read, but in insert statements system shows the message:

```
Unknown system variable `tx_read_only`
```

I have the last version of MySQl

- Hibernate 4
- Java annotations

Can you tell me which is the problem to solve now?

Comment: Check your Spring config/annotations - possibly the transaction is configured as read only?

Comment: Here is my Sprin XMl config file...                                    <!-- Database Configuration -->    
    <import resource="../database/DataSource.xml"/>
    <!-- Hibernate Configuration -->
    <import resource="../database/Hibernate.xml"/>
    <!-- Auto scan the components -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan  
        base-package="BO,DAO"  />
    <!-- Context Manager -->
    <bean id="appContextProvider" class="GUI.AppContextProvider"></bean>
    <!-- JaSypt -->
    <bean id="encryptModule" class="DAO.Util.EncryptModule"></bean>' I don't see that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just throwing rocks to the darkness, but one possibility could be:

- Variable [tx_read_only](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.6-en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tx_read_only) was introduced in MySQL 5.6.5.
- Probably MySQL version is older than that, but Connector/J tries to use new variable anyway.
- According [release notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/en/news-5-1-23.html), support for this variable came in Connector/J 5.1.23.

==> maybe version older than 5.1.23 will work, or this is the bug that is fixed in version newer than that.

Comment: As a extended answer: finally I have no problems with driver 5.1.22 / MySQL database is 6.0.10 version / In this version just only one variable exists with tx_ prefix: TX_ISOLATION... hope MySQL community solve as soon as possible this bug which appeared while I was migrating from HIbernate 3.1 to 4.2 via Spring framework. Thanks Mikko :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was connecting to mariadb with default innodb url format.
So it was selecting the wrong driver
Incorrect: jdbc:mysql://
Correct: jdbc:mariadb://

Answer (score 0):

upgrade mysql-connector-java>=5.1.46

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-1-46.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).