# Mysql Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'

Tags: java, mysql

I have a project written in java `1.6` (used on tomcat `6`). Can't upgrade. I am using connector `5.1.7`. But I have mysql db `8`.

I am getting following error:
`java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'`

That seems pretty logic as [Mysql8 has renamed `tx_isolation` to `transaction_isolation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016980/java-sql-sqlexception-unknown-system-variable-tx-isolation). obviously using mysql connector `8` I am getting `com/mysql/jdbc/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

The question is, is there anything I can do without downgrading my database ?

**EDITED:**
If I downloaded `MySQL server 5.5`, would it be possible to "link" db from currently installed `MySQL server 8` ? (to avoid redundant data replication) ?

Comment: From [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html) link, you need higher jre version.