# HikariCp pool getting Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation' exception

Tags: java, hikaricp

I have an application where user can choose any type and version of database(relational) provide URL, username, password and create datasource, connect to database, then run SELECT queries. To connect database I am using HikariCp for my connection pool(before I used DBCP2 as connection timeout didn't work I changed to HikariCp). Here is my configuration

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();       
config.setDriverClassName(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(driver));      
config.setJdbcUrl(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(url));
config.setUsername(username);
config.setPassword(password);       
config.setMaximumPoolSize(POOL_MAX_ACTIVE);
config.setMinimumIdle(POOL_INITIAL_SIZE);        
config.setConnectionTestQuery(validationQuery);      
config.setConnectionTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(jdbcTimeout));    
HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

When I am trying to connect MYsql database I am getting the following error:

```
HikariPool-8 - Starting... 
2019-04-10  18:45:49  WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase:472 - ReqId:60a79ef60413424e96a4fa73010fc861 - HikariPool-8 - Default transaction isolation level detection failed ((conn=14) Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'). 
2019-04-10  18:45:49 ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:574 - ReqId:60a79ef60413424e96a4fa73010fc861 - HikariPool-8 - Exception during pool initialization. 
java.sql.SQLException: (conn=14) Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:198)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110)
```

What is wrong in the configuration? with DBCP2 it works fine

I am using mariadb-java-client, version: '2.2.1' driver to connect to Mysql database.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016980/java-sql-sqlexception-unknown-system-variable-tx-isolation/51017141#51017141

Comment: I have the same error but I am using MariaDB. Any idea?