# Getting "Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'" error using c3p0 connection pooling

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I am trying to use c3pO connection pooling but getting below error:

Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'

I am using below jars:

mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar

c3p0-0.9.5.3.jar

mchange-commons-java-0.2.15.jar

And below configuration:

```
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="3" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springdemo.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add your error log?

Comment: please check whether the version of your driver / mysql connector matches the version of your back-end database. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016980/java-sql-sqlexception-unknown-system-variable-tx-isolation

Comment: @Tijkijiki I have added the screenshot

Comment: @SteveWaldman I am using mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar and mysql version 8.0.11